# What exactly is operator() in C++ and how to use it

Tags: c++

so I was studying how to define a Comparison function in C++ and I referred to [this article](http://fusharblog.com/3-ways-to-define-comparison-functions-in-cpp/). It introduces a way by doing something like:

```
struct cmp
{
    bool operator()(int a, int b)
    {
        return occurrences[a] < occurrences[b];
    }
};
```

I did some research on this `operator()` but didn't find too much information, so my question is: what exactly `operator()` is and why by doing so can successfully define a comparison function? What is the rationale behind this?